# Salesforce, Unable to create new apex class in Enterprise

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

My account type is Enterprise Edition, i want to create new apex class, but when i try to create new apex from developer console, it shows the error "Cannot create apex class in active organization".
I can login to 'developer.salesforce.com', but when i go to "My Developer Account", and try to create new apex class, still showing error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create or edit Apex or Visualforce in production organizations. You need to create your work in a sandbox and migrate it with a change set, or use an IDE like Eclipse, Illuminated Cloud, etc., to perform a deployment. Keep in mind that when deploying Apex, you will be required to include unit tests for your code to achieve the standard 75% code coverage metrics.

While you can write code in a Developer Edition, you will need an IDE or some other deployment tool to move it to Production, as Developer Editions cannot establish a change set deployment connection. Note that you login to a Developer Edition of Salesforce with your Developer Edition credentials at login.salesforce.com. That's not the same as a Developer Forum or Trailblazer Community account.

If you're not familiar with sandboxes or change sets, I would recommend completing the [Change Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/app_deployment/units/app_deployment_intro) module on Trailhead.

Comment: thanks for reply,
From where i can access sandbox ?

Comment: @uzman, try searching "create sandbox salesforce".  You'll probably find this Salesforce doc:  [Create a Developer or Sandbox Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_get_dev_account.htm)